# How do I get user input and have my other class use it to make calculations?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a program that allows users to input the cost of an order and calculate sales tax and shipping costs based on their input. I want it to be able to provide the user with all of the different costs involved with determining the grand total, as well as the grand total. I am very new to C#, and don't understand why my main class does't recognize the variable names in my second class, and how I can get them to interact. I would greatly appreciate any input. Thanks in advance. Here is my code so far:

```
    class SportGoods
    {

        decimal SubTotal = 0;
        decimal SalesTax = 0;
        decimal ShippingAmount = 0;
        decimal GrandTotal = 0;
        string State = ("");

        public decimal GrandTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public decimal SalesTax { get; set; }
        public decimal ShippingAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal AZTax = 1.05m;
        public decimal CATax = 1.10m;
        public decimal LessThan50 = 12.99m;
        public decimal FiftyTo100 = 4.99m;

        public SportGoods(decimal subTotal, decimal salesTax, decimal 
        shippingAmount, decimal grandTotal)
        {
            SubTotal = subTotal;
            SalesTax = salesTax;
            ShippingAmount = shippingAmount;
            GrandTotal = grandTotal;

        }
        public decimal subTotal
        {
            set
            {
                SubTotal = value;
            }
        }
        public void CalculateSalesTax()
        {
            if (State == "AZ")
            {
                SalesTax = (SubTotal * AZTax) - SubTotal;
            }
            else if (State == "CA")
            {
                 SalesTax = (SubTotal * CATax) - SubTotal;
            }
            else
            {
                SalesTax = 0;
            }
        }
        public void CalculateShipCost()
        {
           if (SubTotal >= 0 && SubTotal < 50 )
           {
                ShippingAmount = LessThan50;
           }
           else if (SubTotal >= 50 && SubTotal < 100)
           {
                ShippingAmount = FiftyTo100;
           }
           else if (SubTotal >= 100)
            {
                ShippingAmount = 0;
            }
           else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your input was invalid");
            }
        }
        public void CalculateGrandTotal()
        {
            GrandTotal = SubTotal + SalesTax + ShippingAmount;
        }

    }
}
```

And my Main:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SportGoods info = new SportGoods((decimal)SubTotal, 
           (decimal)SalesTax, (decimal)ShippingAmount, (decimal)GrandTotal);
           //THE ABOVE CAUSES AN ERROR

            Console.WriteLine("Hello, and welcome to Dan's Sporting 
            Goods. This program will allow you to calculate the tax and 
            shipping charges for any order that you would like to make. 
            Before using the program, please determine what it is you would 
            like to buy from our website, and how much your order will cost 
            in total, before shipping and tax (The subtotal).");

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("How much is the total cost of your order?");
            SubTotal = Console.ReadLine();//THIS CAUSES AN ERROR
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your state's initials (For 
            California, use 'CA', for Arizona, use AZ, etc.):")
            State = Console.ReadLine(); //THIS CAUSES AN ERROR
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare your SubTotal variable.

Comment: What error did you face? From my understanding, 2 place that could cause the issue 1) change `class SportGoods` to `public class SportGoods` 2) declare all `SubTotal`, `SalesTax`, `ShippingAmount`,`OrderTotal` in your `Main` method

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I have it declared in the SportGoods class, and it seems to act as a separate variable when I add it to the main class...

Comment: @gorpmm check my solution below elaborated. thanks

Comment: check my updated answer below.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you expect to happen here. Given the code overwrites the `SalesTax` value based on the `State` value, why is sales tax even passed into the constructor? Likewise shipping amount and grand total? And if these values _are_ needed, why would you try to construct the `SportGoods` object before you have any of these values? The question exhibits such a lack of fundamental understanding of programming, that it seems too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The "variables" you are asking about are undeclared at the point where you use them. If you thought you would get the members of the `SportGoods` class, you need to understand that members of classes can be referenced only in conjunction with a variable referencing an instance of that class (for non-static members) or the name of the class itself (for static members). But if you thought that, it makes me wonder what value you thought those variables would have, given that you haven't created an instance of the class yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put my explanation as comments in the code. Please read. Hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer for class:

```
class SportGoods
    {

        public decimal GrandTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public decimal SalesTax { get; set; }
        public decimal ShippingAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal AZTax = 1.05m;
        public decimal CATax = 1.10m;
        public decimal LessThan50 = 12.99m;
        public decimal FiftyTo100 = 4.99m;

        public SportGoods(decimal subTotal, decimal salesTax, decimal 
        shippingAmount, decimal grandTotal)
        {
            SubTotal = subTotal;
            SalesTax = salesTax;
            ShippingAmount = shippingAmount;
            GrandTotal = grandTotal;

        }
        /* Remove this. It is redundant as SubTotal can do the same. */
        //public decimal subTotal
        //{
        //    set
        //    {
        //        SubTotal = value;
        //    }
        //}

        /* Make this private, we don't need to expose this. 
         * We just need to expose something simple and straight forward. */
        private void CalculateSalesTax()
        {
            if (State == "AZ")
            {
                SalesTax = (SubTotal * AZTax) - SubTotal;
            }
            else if (State == "CA")
            {
                 SalesTax = (SubTotal * CATax) - SubTotal;
            }
            else
            {
                SalesTax = 0;
            }
        }

        /* Make this private, we don't need to expose this. 
         * We just need to expose something simple and straight forward. */
        private void CalculateShipCost()
        {
           if (SubTotal >= 0 && SubTotal < 50 )
           {
                ShippingAmount = LessThan50;
           }
           else if (SubTotal >= 50 && SubTotal < 100)
           {
                ShippingAmount = FiftyTo100;
           }
           else if (SubTotal >= 100)
           {
               ShippingAmount = 0;
           }
           /* Do checking elsewhere. Removed input invalid. */
        }

        /* Make this private, we don't need to expose this. 
         * We just need to expose something simple and straight forward. */
        private void CalculateGrandTotal()
        {
            GrandTotal = SubTotal + SalesTax + ShippingAmount;
        }

        /* Expose this. Just simple method name called "PerformCalculation". Clear cut. */
        public void PerformCalculation()
        {
            CalculateSalesTax();
            CalculateShipCost();
            CalculateGrandTotal();
        }
    }
```

Answer for main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* Initialize everyting to 0 first. */
            SportGoods info = new SportGoods(0,0,0,0);

            /* Use this to check whether user input is valid. I put pass = false first 
             * in order for the while loop logic below to go through at least once. */
            bool pass = false;

            Console.WriteLine(@"Hello, and welcome to Dan's Sporting 
            Goods. This program will allow you to calculate the tax and 
            shipping charges for any order that you would like to make. 
            Before using the program, please determine what it is you would 
            like to buy from our website, and how much your order will cost 
            in total, before shipping and tax (The subtotal).");

            Console.WriteLine("");

            Console.WriteLine(@"How much is the total cost of your order?");

            /* Make sure user enter numeric. As long as the input does not pass 
             * the checking point (pass==false / !pass), show error and continue
             * to loop. */
            while (!pass)
            {
                /* Use try catch to catch error. */
                try
                {
                    /* Convert will throw error if the input is non-numeric. */
                    info.SubTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                    /* If no error is thrown, checking is okay, so set pass = true. */
                    pass = true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input. Please enter numeric value!" + "\n\n");
                    Console.WriteLine(@"How much is the total cost of your order?");
                }
            }

            if (pass)
            {
                /* For simplicity's sake, I don't perform checking for states. */
                Console.WriteLine(@"Please enter your state's initials 
                (For California, use 'CA', for Arizona, use AZ, etc.):");
                info.State = Console.ReadLine();
                /* This is the new method I added in. Refer to SportGoods class. */
                info.PerformCalculation();
                Console.Write("Your Order cost is: " + info.SubTotal + "\n\n");
                Console.Write("Your Sales Tax is: " + info.SalesTax + "\n\n");
                Console.Write("Your Shipping Cost is: " + info.ShippingAmount + "\n\n");
                Console.Write("Your Grand Total is: " + info.GrandTotal + "\n\n");
                Console.Write("Press ENTER to end.");
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you want to reduce the exposed method, might as well also set the AZTax, CATax, LessThan50 and FiftyTo100 as private constant. Only SubTotal need to be fully public, other properties can have their set accessor private. And if it just end up initializing all values as zero, a simple parameterless with empty block constructor will do

Comment: Wow, Thanks! What is the reason for doing the checking in the Main class instead of the SportGoods class?

Comment: @Martheen yes, you are right, but I do not want to modify the original code too much, so that it will be easier for the asker to pick up. ;)

Comment: @gorpmm Generally you'd want the class to only contain *logic* and leave the i/o elsewhere. Thus, the very same class can be used in console app, web app, GUI desktop app, even mobile app.

Comment: @gorpmm, because your original code is trying to "Console.WriteLine("Your input was invalid")" in your class. It is just not what the SportGoods class should do. The class should just stick back to what it is meant to do - Calculate cost and stuff. Let's say one day you want to move your class to web based platform like ASP.NET, then will you need to rewrite that line? If you really want to return an error there, perhaps you can return some error code using enums, and let the caller to perform something whenever they receive the error code - throw errors, send emails, etc.

Comment: @gorpmm, you are just getting started, I would encourage you to pickup you skills from various online sites. I came across this the other day, not sure how good, but looks promising: https://codeasy.net/welcome. Also another one here: https://www.edx.org/school/microsoft, both should be free. Practice more, be curious, and you will be fine. Try to understand what went wrong and why. If you are in college now, pick up as much as you can outside of school hours. Self-taught and school is different IMO. You are in a really fantastic time to learn about technology given the resources available now

Comment: Thanks again. I will check those out. If I want to have my output display the totals in currency format (with a dollar sign, and 2 digits after the decimal point), how would I do that? I tried " Console.WriteLine("The sales tax is: {0:C}", info.SalesTax + "\n\n"); "  but it was still giving me 3 digits after the decimal point sometimes, and no dollar sign

Comment: Well, it is time to do some googling yourself: try google something like "string format currency set culture" or "string.format culture".